# Can someone recommend me a book ( preferably written long ago) that includes all the details of high school chemistry?

Tags: reference-request, erratum

The textbook I got from my teacher is shown to be too general. Part of the fun of learning chemistry, for me, comes from knowing the derivation of equations. But most of the derivations are missing out from the textbook, like the derivation of kinetic molecular equation and real gas equations.

It will be fine to recommend a college level textbook as long as it does not include calculus.

Comment: How about Linus Pauling's "General Chemistry"? Also if you want derivation of equations check out any physical chemistry book. I.e. Atkins.

Comment: But some of them I cannt afford

Comment: @Doeser Pauling's book is a Dover book and goes for about 10 bucks.

Comment: You can find Paulings book for free on the web easily. I think it's copyright has long expired.

Comment: I second Atkins' Physical Chemistry. Also, it's so ubiquitous that I'm sure your local library has or can get hold of a copy from somewhere if you can't afford to buy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"College Chemistry - An Introductory Textbook of General Chemistry" by Linus Pauling (2nd Ed) is available as a free download (pdf & other formats) from https://archive.org/details/CollegeChemistry.